# Trouble accessing sitecore media by ip instead of hostname

Tags: iis, sitecore

I have a problem where due to network issues here I need to access my site via IP not hostname. This causes IIS to recognise the requests as being to the IP (10.0.6.63) instead of the loopback 12.0.0.1

It will find the sitecore_media.ashx fine but the media handler then redirects to 404 instead of serving the media.

Could someone tell me how to get the media handler to accept this request or point me at the doco that explains how it works?

Thanks 
Jim

Comment: I assume you did change the hostname in the <sites> section of the web.config or in the include files and not looking at the default "website" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media handler relies on the SiteResolver to ensure that the correct media items are returned.

As @Martin states - you need to ensure your `<site hostName="">` is correctly configured.  The hostname attribute value is tested against `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`.  If you access your site as `http://127.0.0.1/sitecore` then your hostName is `127.0.0.1`.

Note too that you can put multiple entries into a single **hostName** attribute by pipe (|) separating them.